# How to add fade in animation for each word in text

Tags: javascript, html

I have some text "Eat. Sleep. Repeat.". I want Each word to slide up and fade in, one by one. So Eat fades in, then Sleep, the Repeat. I tried many different methods such as using anime.js, keyframes, adding css class, etc. but none of them got the job done. Here is my code at the moment.

```js
function findelem(tag, text) {
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i].innerHTML == text) {
          return x[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

    function wrapWords (text) {
      words = text.innerHTML.split(" ");
      text.innerHTML = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        text.innerHTML += "<span style = \"opacity: 0; position: relative; top: 30px;\">" + words[i] +  " " + "</span>";
      }
      return text.children
   }
    function animatetext (wordarr) {
      anime({
        targets: wordarr,
        translateY: -30,
        duration: 3000,
        opacity: 1,
        delay: anime.stagger(1000),
      });
    }

    window.onload = function () {
      x = findelem("H1", "Eat. Sleep. Repeat.");
      xarr = wrapWords(x);
      animatetext(xarr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.0.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<h1>Eat. Sleep. Repeat.</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need css for this.  But you need to add some `<span>` elements around your words.  It can be done extremely easy without javascript though.  Here is an example:

```css
h1.fadeIn span{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  display:inline-block;
}

h1.fadeIn span:nth-of-type(2){
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

h1.fadeIn span:nth-of-type(3){
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
  to{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="fadeIn">
  <span>Eat.</span>
  <span>Sleep.</span>
  <span>Repeat.</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: OMG. Guess I have to learn CSS properly. This simplifies life a lot!! Also what does nth-of-type() do? Where can I learn this? Thanks.

Comment: nth of type is just a css selector you can read about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type.  In the example above nth-of-type(2) will select the second sibling and nth-of-type(3) will select the third sibling.  So you are just adding a delay to the fadeIn animation for the second and third span.

Comment: how do i access a specific h1 that contains some text. Can I do that with css or I need js like in my example?

Comment: Just give your h1 a unique class name or id.  I edited my answer above to reflect that.

Comment: thanks. I finally got it. I wanted to do it without modifying the original HTML, so I couldn't specify the class in HTML. So i just added the spans and class in JS, and that in turn triggered the animation. Also the display: inline-block caused the words to have no spacing for me so I fixed this by adding margin-left of 10px. Thanks a million, couldn't have done this without you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working codepen example: 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/rileypaulsen/pen/BvWGRw)
you can modify the values however you like.

```js
const SENTENCE_DELAY = 1000;
let sentencesForFading = document.querySelectorAll('.faded-sentence');

sentencesForFading.forEach(sentence=>{
 sentence.innerHTML = sentence.textContent.split(' ').map(word=>'<span class="faded-word">'+word+'</span>').join(' ');
});


let wordsForFading = document.querySelectorAll('.faded-word');

wordsForFading.forEach(word=>{
 word.addEventListener('transitionend', startNextWordAnimation);
});

function startNextWordAnimation(e){
 let nextWord = e.target.nextElementSibling;
 if( nextWord ){
   nextWord.classList.add('faded-activated');
 } else {
  let nextSentence = e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  startSentence(nextSentence);
 }
}

startSentence(document.querySelector('.faded-sentence'));

function startSentence(sentenceElement){
 if(!sentenceElement){
  return;
 }
 setTimeout(()=>{
  sentenceElement.querySelector('.faded-word').classList.add('faded-activated'); 
 }, SENTENCE_DELAY)
}

document.querySelector('#restart').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
 e.target.blur();
 document.querySelectorAll('.faded-word').forEach(word=>{
  word.classList.remove('faded-activated');
 });
 startSentence(document.querySelector('.faded-sentence'));
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:700");
body {
  background: #003366;
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 40px;
}

p {
  font-size: 21pt;
  color: #CC9900;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.faded-word {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(65%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.faded-activated {
  transition: opacity .2s, transform .3s, color 2s .4s;
  color: #FF3355;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

button {
  font-family: 'Asap', sans-serif;
  background: #CC9900;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 2em;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

button:hover, button:focus {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  filter: brightness(1.1);
}
```

```html
<p class="faded-sentence">This sentence has words that will fade in one by one!</p>
<p class="faded-sentence">It’s completely reusable and isn’t phased by text-wrap.</p>
<button id="restart">Restart Animations</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an animation and some other stuff (in CSS) instead of doing what you're doing.
Then you can fade in a new element each 1 second using `setTimeout`.
Here is your code (I also added some style to the text!):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("h1")[0].style = "animation-name: animation1; animation-duration: 1s; animation-fill-mode: forwards;";

setTimeout(function() { document.getElementsByClassName("h2")[0].style = "animation-name: animation2; animation-duration: 1s; animation-fill-mode: forwards;"; }, 1000);

setTimeout(function() { document.getElementsByClassName("h3")[0].style = "animation-name: animation3; animation-duration: 1s; animation-fill-mode: forwards;"; }, 2000);
```

```css
.h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -100px;
  
}

.h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -100px;
}

.h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -100px;
}

@keyframes animation1 {
  from {color: white; left: -100px;}
  to   {color: black; left: 5px;}
}

@keyframes animation2 {
  from {color: white; left: -100px;}
  to   {color: black; left: 80px;}
}

@keyframes animation3 {
  from {color: white; left: -100px;}
  to   {color: black; left: 190px;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<h1 class="h1">Eat.</h1>
<h1 class="h2">Sleep.</h1>
<h1 class="h3">Repeat.</h1>
```

Here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/abvZqqm